# finding if my linux server is the bottleneck

Tags: linux, performance

I have a redhat linux 6.x server being used for writing of backup images by NetBackup before being dedup to tape library. currently, I have at least 20 servers writing to it every time their backup policy schedule is activated. at 2 of those servers are suffering from backup performance in that what once a 5 hours backup now takes 15 hours.

I have ran `dstat -dnyc -N eth0 -C total -f 5` on my linux box to find possible problem from disk, nic, and cpu. I have below the results however I need help in interpreting them. for example, in the "int" column, I'm getting high numbers there so is it safe to assume that I have network performance issue?

```
--dsk/sda-----dsk/sdb-----dsk/sdc-- --net/eth0- ---system-- ----total-cpu-usage----
 read  writ: read  writ: read  writ| recv  send| int   csw |usr sys idl wai hiq siq
 289k 1700k:  27M   17M:   1B    0 |   0     0 |9111    25k|  5   2  89   5   0   0
   0  2830k:  70M   39M:   0     0 |  74M 1038k|  13k   20k|  6   2  81  10   0   0
   0    62k:  32M  210k:   0     0 |  73M 1049k|  12k   19k|  5   1  84  10   0   0
 430k 1570k:  44M 1741B:   0     0 |  73M 1058k|  15k   25k|  6   2  80  12   0   0
2025k 2181k:  46M  224k:   0     0 |  74M 1012k|  12k   20k|  5   2  82  12   0   0
1493k  104k:  73M  242k:   0     0 |  85M 1060k|  14k   22k|  7   2  80  11   0   0
2002k 1286k:  41M   63M:   0     0 |  97M 1163k|  14k   23k|  6   2  79  12   0   0
2902k 4018k:  53M   56M:   0     0 |  72M 1122k|  16k   25k|  6   2  80  11   0   0
  13k  848k:  60M   36M:   0     0 |  73M 1129k|  13k   20k|  6   2  82  10   0   0
   0  2878k:  65M   13M:   0     0 |  72M 1065k|  14k   20k|  6   2  81  10   0   0
  15k  388k:  41M 8704B:   0     0 |  73M 1029k|  12k   19k|  6   2  82  10   0   0
 124k  574k:  77M   51M:   0     0 |  73M 1067k|  17k   26k|  7   3  80   9   0   0
   0  2942k:  46M  308k:   0     0 |  72M 1020k|  13k   19k|  5   2  83  10   0   0
   0   880k:  62M   51M:   0     0 |  75M 1044k|  13k   20k|  6   2  80  11   0   0
 819B  230k:  59M  819B:   0     0 |  72M 1054k|  12k   19k|  5   2  82  11   0   0
   0  2025k:  66M 2864k:   0     0 |  86M 1141k|  15k   25k|  7   2  80  10   0   0
3277B 4964k:  85M  103M:   0     0 | 108M 1196k|  17k   27k|  9   3  78  10   0   0
   0   117k:  56M 6554B:   0     0 |  81M 1081k|  13k   21k|  6   2  83   9   0   0
   0  1599k:  71M   52M:   0     0 |  77M 1040k|  13k   20k|  6   2  82   9   0   0
   0   464k:  77M    0 :   0     0 |  79M 1109k|  16k   26k|  7   2  80  10   0   0
 638k  714k:  61M   49M:   0     0 |  86M 1096k|  15k   23k|  7   2  79  12   0   0
1350k 2117k:  74M 2097k:   0     0 |  85M 1053k|  14k   22k|  7   2  79  12   0   0
   0  4030k:  32M  218k:   0     0 | 102M 1189k|  13k   23k|  7   2  79  12   0   0
  74k  234k:  26M  101M:   0     0 |  89M 1121k|  15k   27k|  6   2  79  12   0   0
  28k 2563k:  79M   49k:   0     0 |  84M 1076k|  15k   25k|  7   3  78  12   0   0
   0  1102k:  54M   98M:   0     0 | 104M 1149k|  14k   23k|  7   3  80  10   0   0
   0    66k:  94M 5272k:   0     0 |  86M 1091k|  14k   22k|  7   3  81   8   0   0
   0  1931k:  54M  819B:   0     0 |  83M 1085k|  15k   24k|  7   2  81   9   0   0
3277B 3733k:  45M  431k:   0     0 |  76M  997k|  14k   22k|  6   2  82  10   0   0
  13k   50k:  68M   51M:   0     0 |  88M 1105k|  13k   21k|  7   2  81   9   0   0
   0  1447k:  39M  150M:   0     0 |  64M  949k|  16k   21k|  5   2  82  11   0   0
 234k  322k:  44M  464k:   0     0 |  53M  892k|  17k   22k|  5   2  81  12   0   0
7373B  914k:  34M   51M:   0     0 |  75M 1028k|  14k   22k|  5   2  82  11   0   0
   0  2552k:  52M 6861B:   0     0 |  76M 1083k|  14k   21k|  5   2  80  12   0   0
   0  1017k:  77M   51M:   0     0 |  78M 1093k|  14k   22k|  7   2  82   8   0   0
  69k  358k:  49M   42M:   0     0 |  77M 1065k|  15k   25k|  6   2  81  10   0   0
   0  2680k:  62M 9520k:   0     0 |  75M 1022k|  14k   22k|  7   2  81  10   0   0
   0  3934k:  53M 6432k:   0     0 |  76M 1020k|  13k   20k|  6   2  81  11   0   0
   0   175k:  41M  103M:   0     0 |  75M 1053k|  13k   20k|  6   2  81  12   0   0
   0   406k:  59M    0 :   0     0 |  75M 1076k|  13k   21k|  6   2  81  11   0   0
```

did `iostat` also:

```
Linux 2.6.39-200.24.1.el6uek.x86_64 (server)        01/21/2015      _x86_64_        (24 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           4.53    0.00    1.71    4.56    0.00   89.19

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda              82.00       576.99      3400.51 2136449605 12591177064
sdb             198.37     55464.48     35433.85 205369873283 131201919459
sdc               0.00         0.00         0.00       3736          0
dm-0            198.38     55464.48     35433.85 205369869547 131201919459
dm-1            242.48     55464.48     35433.85 205369868931 131201919459
```

and `dd` on disks:

```
time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=8k count=250000 && sync"; rm ddfile
250000+0 records in
250000+0 records out
2048000000 bytes (2.0 GB) copied, 2.13015 s, 961 MB/s

real    0m16.165s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m2.044s
```

they all seem to be normal.

Comment: You can paste it in and use `ctrl-k` on the selected text to format it as code, should preserve line breaks etc.

Comment: Do all of the backups run at the same time, or are they staggered?

Comment: the backups are grouped, some run at night, some at daytime. but when they ran, it will be at least 3 servers doing backups.

Comment: The interrupts *seem* fine, as I believe it's just the disk controller being told to write lots of data (as expected) - I'm sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong.
What is the disk configuration - RAID, etc? Have you benchmarked write-performance to the drive receiving the data from the servers using something like the `dd` tool to create large files?

Comment: The last thing I can think of before I'm admitting I'm stumped! Is it something silly like the backup has grown massively?

Comment: the same db size as i mentioned. but backup is faster on one server (a Sun T4-2), slow on the other (a Sun M5000).